# How to set font family when generating PDF file in html

Tags: html, css

I'm using html for design pdf template, but my pdf not taken proper font-family.it taken default font family.
I have using stRyde font family and font family installed in project folder but it's not generate stRyde font family .below styles use in html.

```
<style>
  @font-face {
     font-family: 'stRyde';
     font-display: fallback;
     src: url('./fonts/StRydeRegular.woff') format("woff"), 
     url('./fonts/StRydeRegular.ttf') format("truetype"), url('./fonts/StRyde- 
     Regular.otf') format("otf");
  }

  html {
     font-family: stRyde, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     --dark-brown: rgb(76, 29, 12);
  }
</style>
```

below screen shot show pdf text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried print media query??

```
@media print {
  selector{
    font-family: .....;  
  }
}
```

But I am not sure if the font desired on print should be installed on the user's device or not.